# Create many to many model where 'at least one' in both directions

Tags: postgresql

Like this A==R==B, A should be involved with at least one B while B also need to be involved with at least one A.

Now I create a new table R, R's PK consists of A's PK and B's PK, but I think I cannot enforce that every A has at least one B or every B has at least one A......Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What are you actually using, MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can enforce it (in MySQL, at least) - but it would be easy to identify and/or delete any instances where it wasn't true.

Comment: can I add some constraint to enforce it?

Comment: In Postgres you can try a deferable constraint trigger on `A` and on `B` for `INSERT`s or `UPDATE`s.